# Почему ajax отправляет два раза post запрос?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Имеется форма с множеством инпутов:

```
<form method="post" id="addForm">
  input
  input
  input
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

ajax:

```
$("#addForm").submit(function(event) {
  // Предотвращаем обычную отправку формы
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post('add.php', $("#addForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
  });
});
```

Обработчик:

```
<? 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
  print_r($_POST); 
} 
?>
```

Файл jquery.js подключен один раз. 
Обработчик выводит массив данных из post запроса  и только один раз, а в  `httpAnalyzer`'e отображает два подряд запроса. Что не так?

Comment: add.php два раза вызывается подряд или все таки один раз ?

Comment: вставьте Echo перед if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' чтобы точно знать сколько раз вызывается скрипт ... Да, кстати а зачем 3 знака === ?

Comment: @Alexus, запрос отправляется на add.php один раз. Файл с формой называется test.php. И кстати в div result  ничего не приходит. Что может быть не так? Три раза ===  ставлю по привычке)) Это типа строгое соблюдение типа. Согласен, в этом месте не к чему.

Comment: Чему равен data в javascript в функции function ?

console.log(data);

Comment: может быть в этом дело?: оба запроса отображаются в снифере по разному - 1. `D:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4+Nginx-1.9\bin\httpd.exe[644] `   2. `D:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4+Nginx-1.9\nginx.exe[2364]`      т.е. в первом присутствует папка `bin` и отличаются цифры в конце

Comment: @Alexus, console выводит - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
(anonymous function)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError... означает что у вас что то не так с jQuery, Эта ошибка у вас возникает всегда или только когда вы вставляете console..log(data) ?

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры не подключен `jquery` на странице. Ошибка стара как мир

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации смотри в консоль браузера. Что там? А если перед `event.preventDefault();` добавить `console.log('test');` сколько раз test попадёт в консоль браузера? Ну и совет @andrey-avseenko можно попробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете сначало submit формы, а потом делаете post запрос. Вот и 2 запроса.

```
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
     на
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
     и
     $("#addForm").submit(function(event)
     на
     $("button").click(function(event)
```